# Mongoose - find() method isn't working with second collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two models in my project - User and Game. The following code behaves very strangely:

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose.js');
var User = require('../models/user').User;
var Game = require('../models/game').Game;

User.count(function(err, count) {
    console.log("users count: " + count); //prints 2
});

Game.count(function(err, count) {
    console.log("games count: " + count); //prints 3
});

User.find(function(err, users) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log("users: ");
    console.log(users); //prints all users
});

Game.find(function(err, games) {
    if(err) throw err; //no error throwed

    console.log("games: "); //This never runs
    console.log(games);
});
```

It's all right with User (logs all users as expected), but Game.find never calls callback.

Another one interesting detail: if "Game" collection is empty, find works properly, prints empty array. But when there are any documents in it, it stops working. Also it doesn't work with mongoose queries.

Also tried to create model with passing third argument like this:

```
exports.Game = mongoose.model('Game', schema, 'Game');
```

But it also works fine only with empty collection

Mongoose module if you need it

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'), config.get('mongoose:options'));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: Are you calling `mongoose.disconnect` somewhere, perhaps before that query completes?

Comment: @JohnnyHK no, I don't

Comment: OK, I think we'll need a [MCVE] if you're still having trouble.